# back-end middleware cannot reach headers, but postman work fine

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-redux, mern

I'm creating new app(e-commerce) using react and react-redux with axios. For back-end using Mongo-DB(MERN stack).

There is no problem when saving data to database, but when i get that data from database middleware can not reach token from headers. But postman work fine both get and save data.

I use the same middleware when saving data to database, it work fine. But when i try to fetch data from database i get unauthorized error.

here is my code.

FOR BACK-END;

Server file;

```
import express from "express";
import connectDB from "./config/db.js";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import colors from "colors";
import productRoutes from "./routes/productRoutes.js";
import userRouters from "./routes/userRoutes.js";
import shippingAddressRoutes from "./routes/shippingAddressRoutes.js";
import { notFound, errorHandler } from "./middleware/errorMiddleware.js";

dotenv.config();

connectDB();

const app = express();

// body parser
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// API route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("API is running....");
});

// route for products
app.use("/api/products", productRoutes);
// route for users
app.use("/api/users", userRouters);
// route for shipping address
app.use("/api/shippingaddress", shippingAddressRoutes);

app.use(notFound);
app.use(errorHandler);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(
    PORT,
    console.log(
        `Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold
    )
);
```

shippingAddressRoute file;

```
import express from "express";
import {
    saveAddress,
    changeAddress,
    getAddress,
} from "../controllers/shippingAddressController.js";
import protect from "../middleware/authMiddleware.js";

const router = express.Router();

router
    .route("/")
    .get(protect, getAddress)
    .post(protect, saveAddress)
    .put(protect, changeAddress);

export default router;
```

shippingAddressController file;

```
import asyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
import ShippingAddress from "../models/shippingAddressModel.js";
import User from "../models/userModel.js";

// @desc   get address
// @route  GET /api/shippingaddress
// @access Private
const getAddress = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const user = User.findById(req.user._id);

    if (user) {
        const { email } = req.body;
        const shippingAddress = await ShippingAddress.findOne({
            userEmail: email,
        });

        if (shippingAddress) {
            res.status(200);
            res.json({
                address: shippingAddress.address,
                city: shippingAddress.city,
                postalCode: shippingAddress.postalCode,
                county: shippingAddress.country,
                email: shippingAddress.userEmail,
            });
        } else {
            res.status(404);
            throw new Error("Address not found");
        }
    } else {
        res.status(404);
        throw new Error("User not found");
    }
});

// @desc   save address
// @route  POST /api/shippingaddress
// @access Private
const saveAddress = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const user = User.findById(req.user._id);

    if (user) {
        const { address, city, postalCode, country, email } = req.body;
        const existAddress = await ShippingAddress.findOne({ userEmail: email });

        if (existAddress) {
            res.status(400);
            throw new Error(
                "User already has an address. If you want to change address, try CHANGE ADDRESS."
            );
        } else {
            const createdAddress = await ShippingAddress.create({
                user: req.user._id,
                address,
                city,
                postalCode,
                country,
                userEmail: email,
            });

            if (createdAddress) {
                res.status(201);
                res.json({
                    address: createdAddress.address,
                    city: createdAddress.city,
                    postalCode: createdAddress.postalCode,
                    county: createdAddress.country,
                    email: createdAddress.userEmail,
                });
            } else {
                res.status(400);
                throw new Error("Address did not save");
            }
        }
    } else {
        res.status(404);
        throw new Error("User not found");
    }
});

// @desc   change address
// @route  PUT /api/shippingaddress
// @access Private
const changeAddress = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    if (user) {
        const { email } = req.body;
        const shippingAddress = await ShippingAddress.findOne({
            userEmail: email,
        });

        if (shippingAddress) {
            shippingAddress.address = req.body.address || shippingAddress.address;
            shippingAddress.city = req.body.city || shippingAddress.city;
            shippingAddress.postalCode =
                req.body.postalCode || shippingAddress.postalCode;
            shippingAddress.country = req.body.country || shippingAddress.country;

            const updatedShippingAddress = await shippingAddress.save();

            res.status(200);
            res.json({
                address: updatedShippingAddress.address,
                city: updatedShippingAddress.city,
                postalCode: updatedShippingAddress.postalCode,
                county: updatedShippingAddress.country,
                email: updatedShippingAddress.userEmail,
            });
        } else {
            res.status(404);
            throw new Error("Address not found");
        }
    } else {
        res.status(404);
        throw new Error("User not found");
    }
});

export { getAddress, saveAddress, changeAddress };
```

authMiddleware file;

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import User from "../models/userModel.js";
import asyncHandler from "express-async-handler";

const protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    let token = req.headers.token;

    if (
        req.headers.authorization &&
        req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")
    ) {
        try {
            // get token from req
            token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
            // verify token
            const decode = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
            // get user from token
            req.user = await User.findById(decode.id).select("-password");

            next();
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(401);
            throw new Error("Not1 Authorized");
        }
    }

    if (!token) {
        res.status(401);
        throw new Error("Not2 Authorized");
    }
});

export default protect;
```

FOR FRONT-END;

shippingAction file;

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import shippingServices from "./shippingServices";

// get address
export const getAddress = createAsyncThunk(
    "shipping/get",

    async (userInfo, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            return await shippingServices.get(userInfo);
        } catch (error) {
            const message =
                (error.response &&
                    error.response.data &&
                    error.response.data.message) ||
                error.message ||
                error.toString();

            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
        }
    }
);

// save address
export const saveAddress = createAsyncThunk(
    "shipping/save",

    async (addressInfo, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            return await shippingServices.save(addressInfo);
        } catch (error) {
            const message =
                (error.response &&
                    error.response.data &&
                    error.response.data.message) ||
                error.message ||
                error.toString();

            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
        }
    }
);

// update address
export const updateAddress = createAsyncThunk(
    "shipping/update",

    async (addressInfo, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            return await shippingServices.update(addressInfo);
        } catch (error) {
            const message =
                (error.response &&
                    error.response.data &&
                    error.response.data.message) ||
                error.message ||
                error.toString();

            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
        }
    }
);
```

shippingServices file;

```
import axios from "axios";

const SHIPPING_ADDRESS_URL = "/api/shippingaddress";

// save address
const save = async (addressInfo) => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${addressInfo.token}`,
        },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.post(SHIPPING_ADDRESS_URL, addressInfo, config);

    return data;
};

// get address
const get = async (userInfo) => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
        },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.get(SHIPPING_ADDRESS_URL, userInfo, config);

    return data;
};

// update address
const update = async (addressInfo) => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${addressInfo.token}`,
        },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.put(SHIPPING_ADDRESS_URL, addressInfo, config);

    return data;
};

const shippingServices = {
    save,
    get,
    update,
};

export default shippingServices;
```

shippigPage file;

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import FormContainer from "../components/FormContainer";
import Message from "../components/Message";
import Loader from "../components/Loader";
import { shippingSliceAction } from "../features/shipping/shippingSlice";
import { saveAddress, getAddress } from "../features/shipping/shippingAction";

function ShippingPage() {
    const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
    const { shippingAddress, isLoading, isSuccess, isError, message } =
        useSelector((state) => state.shipping);
    const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
    const [city, setCity] = useState("");
    const [postalCode, setPostalCode] = useState("");
    const [country, setCountry] = useState("");
    const [comMessage, setComMessage] = useState(null);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (shippingAddress) {
            setAddress(shippingAddress.address);
            setCity(shippingAddress.city);
            setPostalCode(shippingAddress.postalCode);
            setCountry(shippingAddress.country);
        } else {
            const userInfo = {
                token: user.token,
                email: user.email,
            };
            dispatch(getAddress(userInfo));
        }
    }, []);

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!user) {
            navigate("/login");
        } else {
            if (!address || !city || !postalCode || !country) {
                setComMessage("Please fill all fields");
                setTimeout(() => setComMessage(null), 3000);
            } else {
                dispatch(
                    shippingSliceAction.takeAddress({
                        email: user.email,
                        address,
                        city,
                        postalCode,
                        country,
                    })
                );
                localStorage.setItem(
                    "userAddress",
                    JSON.stringify({
                        email: user.email,
                        address,
                        city,
                        postalCode,
                        country,
                    })
                );
            }
        }
    };

    const saveContinue = () => {
        if (!user) {
            navigate("/login");
        } else {
            dispatch(
                saveAddress({
                    email: user.email,
                    address,
                    city,
                    postalCode,
                    country,
                    token: user.token,
                })
            );
            if (isSuccess) {
                setComMessage("Your Address Saved");
                setTimeout(() => dispatch(shippingSliceAction.reset()), 3000);
                setTimeout(() => setComMessage(null), 3000);
                setTimeout(() => navigate("/payment"), 4000);
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <FormContainer>
            <h1>Shipping</h1>
            {comMessage && <Message variant="danger">{comMessage}</Message>}
            <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                <Form.Group controlId="address">
                    <Form.Label>Address</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter Address"
                        value={address}
                        onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
                    ></Form.Control>
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="city">
                    <Form.Label>City</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter City"
                        value={city}
                        onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
                    ></Form.Control>
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="postalCode">
                    <Form.Label>Postal Code</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="number"
                        placeholder="Enter Postal Code"
                        value={postalCode}
                        onChange={(e) => setPostalCode(e.target.value)}
                    ></Form.Control>
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="country">
                    <Form.Label>Country</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Enter Country"
                        value={country}
                        onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)}
                    ></Form.Control>
                </Form.Group>

                <Button className="shippingButton" type="submit" variant="primary">
                    Continue without saving
                </Button>

                {isLoading && <Loader />}
                {isSuccess && <Message variant="success"></Message>}
                {isError && <Message variant="danger">{message}</Message>}
                <Button
                    className="shippingButton save"
                    type="button"
                    variant="secondary"
                    onClick={saveContinue}
                >
                    Save my address and continue
                </Button>
            </Form>
        </FormContainer>
    );
}

export default ShippingPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// shippingServices.js
const { data } = await axios.get(SHIPPING_ADDRESS_URL, userInfo, config);
```

this should be

```js
const { data } = await axios.get(SHIPPING_ADDRESS_URL, config);
```

Also stop using unnecessary packages like `express-async-handler`,
just cover entire middle-ware function body with `try/catch` block, call `next(error)` in catch block & it will work just fine.

Comment: thanks for your reply, this works fine. i try to improve my skills.